# Variance of |X-Y| for X and Y ~ N(0,1/2)

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I know $X$ and $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\frac12)$, $X$ and $Y$ are independent. I try the  following way to solve variance of $g(X,Y)=|X-Y|$ ,which is $V(|X-Y|)$.
If $X>Y$，$V(|X-Y|)=V(X-Y)=V(X)+V(Y)=\frac12+\frac12=1$
(If $X<Y$, $V(|X-Y|)$ is also 1)
Hence,$V(|X-Y|)=1$.
What's wrong with the answer of my first method (which seems concise and easy to calculate)?

Comment: You have to be very careful when you split up a calculation of variance over disjoint events. Your first calculation is $V(|X - Y|)$ given $X > Y$, which equals $V(X | X > Y) + V(Y | X > Y)$. These two numbers might not equal 1/2. Furthermore, even if each of the answers were $1$, it doesn't mean the final variance is $1$.

Comment: @Alex Zorn, Thank you for reminding me of  $X$ and $Y$ are random variables! And I shouldn't have forgotten the conditional raw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $-Y$ is also $N\left(0,\frac12\right)$. Thus, $X-Y$ is the sum of two $N\left(0,\frac12\right)$ variables, which is a $N(0,1)$ variable.

The absolute value of a $N(0,1)$ variable has the PDF
$$
\sqrt{\frac2\pi}e^{-x^2/2}[x\ge0]
$$
where $[\cdot]$ are [Iverson Brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

Using the substitution $t=x^2/2$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\int_0^\infty xe^{-x^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\sqrt{\frac2\pi}
\end{align}
$$
and integrating by parts
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-x^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=-\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\int_0^\infty x\,\mathrm{d}e^{-x^2/2}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\[6pt]
&=1
\end{align}
$$
So the variance is the mean of the square minus the square of the mean:
$$
1-\frac2\pi=\frac{\pi-2}\pi
$$

Comment: John, your answer can perfectly solve  $V(|D-X|)$  but I still confused about what's wrong with my own method.

Comment: The characters you are using make it hard to figure out what you are doing. If you use MathJax only, and not use non-ASCII characters, we could better tell what you are trying to do.

Comment: @user229922 He's Robert, not John. =)

Comment: Pedro (or Tamaroff), thanks for reminding :-)

Answer (score 2):

As $X$ and $Y$ are independant, $X-Y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, so $V(|X-Y|)=V(|Z|)$ where $Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

$V(|Z|) = E(|Z|^2)-E(|Z|)^2 = E(Z^2)-E(|Z|)^2$.

$E(Z^2)=V(Z)=1$. Now all you have to do is finding $E(|Z|)$ where $Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ (calculate the corresponding integral for example).

Comment: Augustin, Thank you for you method which seems easy to use. But can you point out what's wrong with my method?

Comment: I don't really understand what you did.

Comment: Since the sum of two independent variables has the mean and variance the sum of the individual means and variances, isn't the sum of two $\mathcal{N}\left(0,\frac12\right)$ variables (each with variance $\frac14$) a $\mathcal{N}\left(0,\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)$ variable (with variance $\frac12$)?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I understood that $\frac{1}{2}$ was the variance of $X$ and $Y$, not the standard deviation.

Comment: Ah, yes. I just looked it up and indeed, the variance is $\frac12$ and not the standard deviation. Gotta fix my answer.